# Segue as a new view

Tags: swift, segue

I have a navigation controller as a root view to the home view then a sign in view then the main view. When I sign in and segue to the main view using

```
vc.performSegueWithIdentifier("toMenuView", sender: nil)
```

I can slide back to the sign in view. I don't want that. How can I segue to the main view without having access to going back unless the user taps the sign out button and then goes back to the home view without again having access to go "back" to the main view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For gesture recogniser to swipe back to previous page.

`self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = false`

If you have a navigation bar, you might need to hide it too. Else you can also hide the back button by:

`self.navigationController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.enabled = false`

Comment: I forgot to mention that theres a root navigation controller, but yeah I've hid the back button but the swiping is still there. Will this hide it or get rid of it?

Comment: After you hide the back button, you just use the first line of code inside your viewDidLoad method and there is no way how to go back to previous page. Unless you code it yourself.

Comment: Is it possible to not have it hidden but completely over to the next view?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: Basically is it possible to do it without hiding the back button or disabling the swipe?

Comment: You will need to programatically enable or disable such feature. This is because the settings you see are default settings. In fact, what is the purpose of having a back button that doesn't work?

Comment: For example a simple two view controllers you can't go back. That's like what I meant by.

Comment: You can do it using modal presentation. You can search on google for this. It is a better implementation for login functions.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look it up.